# Cargar imágenes con diferentes tamaños usando Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

**Buenas, estoy tratando de cargar imágenes de diferentes `urls` como esta: [Link](https://lectortmo.com/viewer/656f0c7d9478ae21cbd6b1060749b645/cascade)

Como pueden ver, las imágenes tienen diferentes tamaños. Por ejemplo, la primer imagen tiene un tamaño de 1920x1280, la segunda tiene un tamaño de 720x11523 y la última un tamaño de 720x5420. Al momento de cargar sucede lo siguiente en mi aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
1- La primer imagen sobrepasa el ancho de la pantalla por lo que corta
2- En la segunda imagen se ve que no ocupa todo el ancho y no queda centrada
```

Otro ejemplo, es este [Link](https://lectortmo.com/viewer/ce158a25318218217f3a4b76bafa9ba4/cascade)

Como pueden ver, también tienen diferentes tamaños. La primer imagen tiene un tamaño de 1702x1080, la segunda imagen un tamaño de 1170x1618 y la última un tamaño de 986x1238. Los errores aquí siguen siendo los mismos que ya he mencionado.

Este es mi layout para el adaptador:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blanco">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Mi clase adaptador:

```
public class TMOnlineLectorAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases;
    private Context context;

    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoItems, Context context) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = tmoItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adaptador_lectortmo, parent, false);
        return new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClases.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.iv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tmoLectorClases.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView iv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> newList) {
        tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
        tmoLectorClases.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = items;
    }
}
```

El layout de la actividad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TMO.TMOnlineLector"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCapitulosSeleccion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

La actividad:

```
private String url = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmonline_lector);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvCapitulosSeleccion);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(tmoLectorClases, TMOnlineLector.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();
}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TMOLectorClase>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        //Actualizar información
        adapter.updateData(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        tmoLectorClases.clear();
        try {
            String nuevaUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute().url().toExternalForm();
            Log.d("Items", "Url: " + nuevaUrl);

            if(nuevaUrl.contains("/paginated")){
                nuevaUrl = nuevaUrl.replaceAll("/paginated", "/cascade");
                Log.d("items", "doInBackground: " + nuevaUrl);

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();
                Log.d("Items", "Url: " + doc);

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = "";
                    if(e.select("div.img-container.text-center").size() > 0)
                    imgUrl = e.select("img").get(0).attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("TAG", "doInBackground: " + imgUrl);
                    //String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }else{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("items", "doInBackground: "+ imgUrl);
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoLectorClases;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar los problemas mencionados? Intenté usando esto :

```
Picasso.with(context)
               .load(tmoLectorClase.getImg())
               .fit()
               .centerCrop()
               .into(holder.iv);
```

Pero, por algún motivo con el `fit()` no me carga ninguna imagen.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Siguiendo la sugerencia del usuario `Jorgesys` he campiado las propiedades del `CardView` dejándolas cómo:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Pero esto ocasiona que la primer imagen se vea recortada y el resto ni siquiera se visualice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta sucediendo no lo causa Picasso, en realidad es el contenedor que en este caso es un `CardView`, por lo tanto en esta vista debes definir al menos la propiedad "match_parent" ya sea para la altura o el ancho:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blanco">
```

Comment: He hecho como dices, ahora a excitación de la primer imagen, el resto no se visualiza y la primer imagen se ve más cortada.

Comment: Ah, es que si es horizontal tu pager no uses match_parent, usa wrap_content